# Read a file without the input button javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, dojo

The file we are talking about is of type zip

```
    <input type="file" id="file-input" name="files[]" accept="application/zip"/>
```

Code in dojo..

```
   fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
                    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
                        console.log("File success");
                        console.log(fileInput.files[0]);
                        zipParser(fileInput.files[0]);
                    },false);
```

means the on click on button gets the finder/explorer..select the zip file and on the change listner we get the instance of file

console.log shows

```
File success 
tpk-layer1.html:168 File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Tue Sep 09 2014 11:50:18 GMT+0530 (IST), name: "Beirut.zip", type: "application/zip", size: 14263592…}lastModifiedDate: Tue Sep 09 2014 11:50:18 GMT+0530 (IST)name: "Beirut.zip"size: 14263592type: "application/zip"webkitRelativePath: ""__proto__: File
```

I dont want the button instance .That is this onclick and listner needs to be removed and should call the file directly onload of page..

How can i achieve this.Please let me know if any clarification is required

More info

I have tried calling

```
zipParser('/samples/tpks/Beirut.zip');
```

But got the response as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.
```

Please note this is for **Phonegap application**

Comment: How would you know which file to load on page load?

Comment: It is a zip file a single file i have with me.Can be included in the source code

Comment: Yikes, that last bit is a pretty big edit. I've added phonegap as a tag as AJAX will not work if you want to pull files from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a blob you need, you can use XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
       var blob = this.response;
       // Call zipParser?
       zipParser(blob);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', './yourZipFile.zip');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```

Comment: @LithuT.V No problem, nice when a wild stab in the dark pays off!